# Why CreateView with ModelForm showing model fields twice

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168446/how-to-use-django-summernote-in-templates/52175327#52175327) 
I was looking to use django-summernote without forms but it seems Impossible, so I decided to use forms and when I read the Doc about "Form handling with class-based views" [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)
it says :

> These generic views will automatically create a ModelForm

I think because of this my fields are showing twice on my template (in admin it works greats) that because i made a ModelForm and generic view (CreateView) make another one!

I want to know how to solve this

my Models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    game_trailer = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="No Trailer")
    game_story = models.TextField(default='No Story')
```

my main urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('games/', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
]
```

my app(name=core) urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/', views.GameCreate.as_view(), name='game_new'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', views.GameUpdate.as_view(), name='game_edit'),
]
```

my views.py :

```
class GameCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Game
    template_name = 'core/game_new.html'
    form_class = GameForm
    redirect_field_name = 'home'

class GameUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'core/game_edit.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

my forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget

from core.models import Game


class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'game_story': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

my template file "game_new.html" :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %} Add New Game {% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<section class="main-section">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>New Game</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            {{ form|safe }}
            <input type='submit' value="Save" />
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

my template file "game_edit.html":

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %} Game Info {% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<section class="main-section"></section>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Edit Game Info</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

**Note :**
to explain the problem here every field that 'Game Model' has is showing in my template twice.

Screenshot [the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qib0o.png)

Comment: try change `{{ form|crispy }} {{ form|safe }}` to `{{ form|crispy|safe }}` in `game_new.html`

Comment: Hi @Ykh before your replay i remove {{ form|safe }} and everything worked very good , and now i add this ` {{ form|crispy|safe }} ` and this worked too , can you please explain what  ` {{ form|safe }} ` is for with your solution in answer so i can accept the answer

Comment: `|safe` is used for cast html code to html,i think it's not needed.`{{ form|crispy }}` will fine for `form`.If you have multi template tag for one object, write as `{{ object|tag1|tag2 }}`

Comment: @Yky please answer the question below so i can accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|safe` is used for cast html code to html,i think it's not needed.`{{ form|crispy }}` will fine for form.If you have multi template tag for one object, write as `{{ object|tag1|tag2 }}`